# If the $4$th and $7$th terms of a Harmonic Progression are $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{5}$, then what is the first and $n$th term?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So $t_{4} = \frac{2}{3}$ and $t_{7} = \frac{2}{5}$

So $t_{n}$ of a HP is $\dfrac{1}{t_{n} \mbox{of an AP}}$

$\therefore t_{4} = \frac{1}{a + 3d}$ and $t_{7} = \frac{1}{a + 6d}$

I then substituted the values of the given terms to get two equations, but my answer is wrong for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the reciprocal AP, 4th term is $3/2$ and 7th term is $5/2$ and hence the common difference is $1/3$ and the general term is $1/2 + (n-1)/3$. Thus the general term of HP is $\frac{1}{1/2 + (n-1)/3}$